# Famo.us paginated scrollview current page/view

Tags: famo.us

What would be the the best way to get the current view/page in paginated scrollview?

There are only gotonextpage and gotoprevious page methods in scrollview. I know I have some data at hand on scrollview.sync.on('end') event, but that looks like I need to calculate my self the current view/page somehow. (like the Shine demo with scroller)

There must be some easier approach I haven't spotted.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Returns the position associated with the Scrollview instance's current node (generally the node currently at the top).
     
    Scrollview.prototype.getPosition = function getPosition() {
        return this._particle.getPosition1D();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in coffeescript:

```
coverView.on 'pageChange', (e) -> 
  p = coverView.getPosition()   # some weird value
  n = coverView._node.index
  console.log('coverView', e, n, p)
```

however, this only seems to work in one direction :)

https://github.com/Famous/views/issues/67

Comment: This was something i was looking for. The direction bug is still present though. I used the fix as described in the issue 67.